# get word index in string match

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I have two strings.

`str = "This is an example sentence, it is for demonstration only"`

`k = "example sentence"` # k might contain one word or many

I want to find `k` in `str` but I need word index.
I split the `str`

`splitted_str = str.split()`

```
print(splitted_str)
['This', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'sentence,', 'it', 'is', 'for', 'demonstration', 'only']
```

if I match `k` in `splitted_str` then function should give me index of `example` as 3 and index of `sentence` as 4.

`re.search().start()` it gives string starting index only.

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First search `k` in `str`, find the character index, then split the part of `str` up to that index.

Answer (score 2):

Try splitting the sentence on your phrase, and then count the words coming before it.

```
>>> str = "This is an example sentence, it is for demonstration only"
>>>
>>> k = "example sentence"
>>> str.split(k)
['This is an ', ', it is for demonstration only']
>>> str.split(k)[0].split()
['This', 'is', 'an']
>>> len(str.split(k)[0].split())
3
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks @Harvey. What if I don't know `k` has one word or multiple words. Any update.

Comment: If `k` contains multiple words, count them and add to the initial word count: `3` + (`0`, `1`, ...)

Comment: Thanks I made it like this
def matcher(text, word):
    split_word = word.split()
    split_text = text.split(word)

    if (len(split_text) > 1):
        start = len(split_text[0].split())
        print(start)
        end = start + len(split_word) - 1
        print(end)